# How to set currentUser() for QBChat?

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

How can i set the currentUser as below?

Big Thank

```
guard let currentUser = ServicesManager.instance().currentUser() else{
      return
    }

    currentUser.fullName = defaultCurrentUserFullName
    currentUser.password = defaultCurrentUserPassword


error shown
2017-05-28 05:51:58.346 FreeChat[2615:41904] Init - QMAuthService service...
2017-05-28 05:51:58.347 FreeChat[2615:41904] Init - QMChatService service...
2017-05-28 05:51:58.350 FreeChat[2615:41967] [QBCore] Restoring QBSession,  status = -25300. See "Security Error Codes" (SecBase.h)
2017-05-28 05:51:58.355 FreeChat[2615:41904] Init - QMUsersService service...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should log in with this user.

```
/**
 *  User login
 *
 *  @param user       QuickBlox User
 *  @param completion completion block
 *
 *  @return Cancelable request
 */
- (QBRequest *)logInWithUser:(QBUUser *)user
                  completion:(nullable void(^)(QBResponse *response, QBUUser * _Nullable userProfile))completion;
```

We're going to make the method ServicesManager.instance().currentUser() as read-only property or remove it in future releases.